# LevelDB in Node.js worker thread

Tags: node.js, worker

I'm unable to require level down module in node.js worker thread:

```
var levelup = require('levelup')
var leveldown = require('leveldown')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>
Hello from main!

events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
```

Please help how to figure this.

Comment: Which version of node are you using ?

Comment: 10.8.0 version node

Comment: It seems that you are using node module that are note compiled for your architecture.
Did you try to npm rebuild you modules.
Try also a node-gyp rebuild ;)

Comment: Exact same issue here and no solution.